# PHP design patterns Factories

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns, refactoring, factories

We make heavy use of the factory pattern, its create in situations where orchestrating the creation of entities (models) that have many different relationships and parameters. Great!

**Although, I'm looking for a similar pattern for updating that same entity, is there one?**

At present we update models in our `Repositories` as much of the Laravel community does. Although this to me is a code smell. Repositories are responsible for retrieving groups of entities, nothing more... Is there a term / pattern to cover this *Creator* / *Factory* paradigm?

To cut those Laravel fan boys down before they begin: Yes we are a large enough app to warrant these considerations. It has come to the point we need to split this logic away from our repositories...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for. It looks like you're unhappy with your [1] `Repositories` updating your [2] `ActiveRecord` models to reflect your database. So, you want to not use Repositories, ActiveRecord or both?

Comment: Yes we use eloquent (active record), we use repositories. Although they should not be used for updating models...

Comment: Active Record should not be used for update? Really?

Comment: No no. Repositories should not be sued for updating models. It breaks the single responsibility principal. Our repos are large we want to abstract this logic out of them